STM32F030x Slave I2C device respond on 2 addresses
I have a project for simple switcher. I'm trying to configure the I2C communication in my project, after the Initialization my slave device respond on 2 addresses, one of this is i need(I configure it in header file). But the slave device respond on other address also(0x40). I really don't understand what is the problem because i'm not allowed the DualAddressing mode or the OwnAddressConfig.
Here's my initialization code:
void i2c_Initialization() 
{
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE); 
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);

    I2C_InitTypeDef i2c;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef port;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef nvic;

    port.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    port.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;     
    port.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;          
    port.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;      
    port.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;        
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &port);

    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_1);

    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannel = I2C1_IRQn;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = 0;
    nvic.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&nvic);

    //I2C_DeInit(I2C1);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, DISABLE);
        
    I2C_StructInit(&i2c);
    i2c.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;                    
    i2c.I2C_OwnAddress1 = (I2C_SLAVE_ADDR) << 1;    
        i2c.I2C_SlaveAddressConfig = I2C_SLAVE_ADDR <<1;
    i2c.I2C_Timing =                        
            (0xB  << I2C_OFFSET_TIMINGR_PRESC)|\
            (0x13 << I2C_OFFSET_TIMINGR_SCLL)|\
            (0xF  << I2C_OFFSET_TIMINGR_SCLH)|\
            (0x4  << I2C_OFFSET_TIMINGR_SCLDEL)|\
            (0x2  << I2C_OFFSET_TIMINGR_SDADEL);
    i2c.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
        
        
    //I2C_ITConfig(I2C_IT_TCI | I2C_IT_ADDRI | I2C_IT_RXI | I2C_IT_TXI, ENABLE);
    I2C_ITConfig(I2C1, I2C_IT_ADDRI | I2C_IT_RXI | I2C_IT_STOPI, ENABLE);

    I2C_Init(I2C1, &i2c);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
    //while ((I2C1->CR1 & I2C_CR1_PE)==0) {};   
}

As i said the header file consists the slave address. I think it doesn't matter what code provides the header i2c file(the readBuffer, commands and the crc checksum)
I think all the problem is in the multiplexer, but when i configure the switch withount it also have a same problem. The slave device respond on 1 address(legit) and the second(0x40). What is excatly doing with this? Am i need to configure the DualAddressCmd strictly or make something like I2C_OwnAddress2Config?
The slave i2c device needs to be respond only on 1 address, now they're respond both the 0x10 and 0x40

What is the original address? Also, you have i2c.I2C_OwnAddress1 = (I2C_SLAVE_ADDR) << 1;             i2c.I2C_SlaveAddressConfig = I2C_SLAVE_ADDR <<1; I don't know what exactly these lines do, the first line seems to actually set own slave address. What does the second part of it do? It looks very much like repetition of the first line, but since it's a different thing, it could do something else.

I2C_SlaveAddressConfig seems to be a config for I2C master (slave address to initiate communication with). You should probably remove that line.

@Ilya the original address of slave device is 0x10, it's hardcoded in .h file, the second is I2C_SlaveAddressConfig  the SPL's library define function. You're probably right with this remark, thanks. I'm tried to run-up switcher and still have a same problem with dual-addressing, i'm also write the irqHandler for wire, but there is no event that can start the handler, so the code still working properly

Out of curiosity: what will happen if you configure two slave addresses for MCU's I2C, both with the same address?

It's pretty good idea, i'm tryna do it when i was work, but firstly i need to figure out how to do it in switcher.
